# como puedo rellenar un textbox al seleccionar un elemento de un comboBox?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private void pruebas_load(object sender, EventsArgs e)
{ 
  If (cb2.selectedIndex >0)
   {
     String[] valores = combo.captar_info(cb2.text)
     Txtcosto.text = valores[0];
   }
}
```

Este es el código para que al momento de seleccionar un elemento de un combobox se llene el textbox y no lo hace.

Comment: Que es lo que quieres poner en el `TextBox` una vez seleccionas el `Item  del `ComboBox`? Qué contiene la clase `combo.captarInfo()`? Falta información para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: Por un lado, obviamente el problema podría estar en tu método `combo.captar_info` que no nos muestras, con lo que no podemos ayudarte. Además,como ya te comentan en una respuesta, debes meter tu código dentro del evento `SelectedIndexChanged` del combobox. Por otro lado,esto no es C# sino vb.net, he cambiado el tag.

Answer (score 0):

Sí te refieres a obtener el valor del elemento seleccionado en el ComboBox e insertarlo dentro del TextBox tienes que utilizar Eventos que te facilita el elemento ComboBox que saltan al realizar/hacer acciones sobre dicho elemento, en este caso necesitas el uso del evento "SelectedValueChanged":

```
private void cb2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (cb2.SelectedIndex == 0) {
            Txtcosto.Text = "";
    } else {
            Txtcosto.Text = combo.captar_info(cb2.Text)[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Al momento de seleccionar un elemento de un combobox nesecito rellenar el textbox

Comment: Pero se va a rellenar desde una columna de base de datos

Comment: He modificado según lo que comentas, los valores se obtienen a partir de la función combo.captar_info según el valor del ComboBox seleccionado y se pasa al Textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Tambien podria ser

private void cb2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){

```
   textbox.text = combobox.selectitem();
    o
   textbox.text = combobox.text;
```

}